# How to order rows EXACTLY like the image given?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

so I have been given an image and you have to create an output from your table via SQL. I managed to display the Employee Names with the assigned Manager Names but the order of the names did not match the question.

I am thinking ORDER BY WHERE may be used?
Do you think this will help because I don't think I'm implying this correctly maybe
https://sqlandme.com/2013/11/18/sql-server-custom-sorting-in-order-by-clause/

**REQUIRED:**

[image]

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(m.TITLEOFCOURTESY,' '),m.FIRSTNAME),' '),m.LASTNAME) AS "Manager Name",CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(a.TITLEOFCOURTESY,' '),a.FIRSTNAME),' '),a.LASTNAME) AS "Employee Name"
FROM EMPLOYEES a
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES m
ON a.REPORTSTO = m.EMPLOYEEID;
```

**MY OUTPUT:**

[image]

STEVEN should be third but he is actually second.

Comment: STEVEN should be 2nd but he is actually 3rd

Comment: why  ??? which is the logic for the order by ?

Comment: Without seeing the data in the `EMPLOYEES` table it's impossible to guess what the appropriate way to sort is

Comment: The employees are not sorted by any permutation of `titleofcourtesy, firstname, lastname`. So the sort order must be derived from some other attribute of EMPLOYEES. Salary? Hiredate? Alas we cannot tell you because we cannot see your schema. You'll have to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: The required order doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Are you sure the 'must look as follows' instruction actually includes the ordering - it isn't just specifying the formatting of the names? (You should usually order the output anyway, of course, but you have to know the criteria to use.)

Comment: @AlexPoole - good point. Maybe we've all been too literal in our interpretation. It's a shame students can't send their assignments back ticked *Unclear what you're asking*.

Comment: I'll check with my lecturer. Thank you guys.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I did ORDER BY TITLE 
(Which is something not shown to you guys in my images)
AND IT WORKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to order by the employee name you can paste the same condition in the select to the order by clause.

Judging by the expected output it looks like it is also ordered by salary, department or another column you didn't mention in the question.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the concatenation; you can `order by "Employee Name"`. The output in the image clearly isn't ordered by that though.